# Has completing the entire Talmud ever been a tenet of Rabbinical Ordination?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, semicha

Has there ever been a requirement in any Rabbinical program to finish the entire Talmud, not just select mesechtas + related halachos?

Comment: How about the four out of six relevant seddarim to become a gaon? Does that count?

Comment: @user6591 what about Brisk? ;)

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Ha. No I'm serious. In order to become a gaon, head of the academy in gaonic times, one had to know the four seddarim (some extra masechtos were thrown in like Nida Chulin Brachos etc) by heart. Is that what you are looking for? Or are you exclusively looking for knowledge of all six?

Comment: @user6591 All 6 (and even Jerusalem, but I guess that wasn't widespread in Europe until recently?), not necessarily baal peh

Comment: I'd upvoted before, just one more thing. Learning of whichever seddarim seems to be cyclical. See the gemara in Brachos 20a אמר ליה רב פפא לאביי מאי שנא ראשונים דאתרחיש להו ניסא ומאי שנא אנן דלא מתרחיש לן ניסא אי משום תנויי בשני דרב יהודה כולי תנויי בנזיקין הוה ואנן קא מתנינן שיתא סדרי וכי הוה מטי רב יהודה בעוקצין האשה שכובשת ירק בקדרה ואמרי לה זיתים שכבשן בטרפיהן טהורים אמר הויות דרב ושמואל קא חזינא הכא ואנן קא מתנינן בעוקצין תליסר מתיבתא

Comment: Maybe before the days of shulchan aruch. I doubt nowadays